# Report Viewer - Find - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

In Report Viewer, I have a report that displays correctly.  However, when I try to find a string of text by typing the keyword in the search box and clicking "Find," I am receiving

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I read online that this could occur if there is a column with a width < 0.05 inches, but that is not the case with this report - the narrowest column is 0.75 inches.

Are there any other known causes of this error?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into this [thread](http://www.bi-rootdata.com/2012/10/an-error-occurred-during-client.html). It might help you.